# CSRF Token is not passed to request header in Laravel / VueJS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

When trying to make a GET request, I get a

> 401: {error: "Unauthenticated."}

When I check request headers in chrome debugger, I can see `x-requested-with:XMLHttpRequest`, but I can't see crsf-token

I use passport, and I have enabled `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware

In my HTML, I have:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {
        csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    };
    var csrfToken = "{{csrf_token()}}";
</script>
```

In my VueJS, I have:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', csrfToken);
});
```

I still perform query with JQuery :

```
this.$http.post('/api/v1/associations/create', this.form)
.then(...)
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: please try passing the token explicitly and make sure it works with token. If you can confirm that, then we can narrow down the problem to frontend.

Comment: I don t know how to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

The `Unauthenticated` means that the user is not logged in and it does not relate to csrf_token.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing `this.$http.post` by axios, and in `boostrap.js`, I just uncommented:

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
```